# How can I provide multiple destination (clusters) when using Git Generator (in an ArgoCD applicationset)?

Tags: devops, continuous-deployment, cicd, argocd, argo

I am leveraging Git Directory Generator and want to see if there is a way to provide multiple destinations (Multiple K8s clusters)

In the list generator, I can provide elements with `cluster`, `url` & `path`. How can I provide the same when using Git generator?

Ref: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/applicationset/Generators-Git/#git-generator-directories

Comment: Just to clarify: with the list generator, you can provide anything under any name. You could provide a `foo` variable that actually contains a cluster name.

Comment: Regarding the usage of git generator. Could you describe how you're using it? What's the folder structure? Does the cluster name appears in the folder path? Or maybe you want a matrix generator to combine git generator and list generator?

Comment: Hi Gael, I will get back to you in a day.